# Inheriting ActionBarSherlock and Android YouTubePlayer

Tags: android, youtube-api, actionbarsherlock, multiple-inheritance

I've developed an app for playing youtube videos using ActionBarSherlock.

Now that the YouTubePlayer api for android is available ([here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer)), I want to integrate this into my app to improve playback and controls.

I've run into an issue, in that I need to use multiple inheritance for my activity to both extend `SherlockActivity` and also `YouTubeBaseActivity`.

I checked out [this article](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/patterns/multipleinheritance.html) to try to understand multiple inheritance in Java, but frankly it's over my head.

If I attempt to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5836735/522660) I get the issue that I can't instantiate `SherlockActivity`.

Anyone have some concrete example of how to extend both classes?  Has anyone had to extend both `SherlockActivity` and some other class, and how did you accomplish?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problems - I wanted to add YouTube player to my app, but albo I don't wanted to delete Sherlock from it (based on support library). And what is bad, I wasnt able to use any of the playbers, because I got errors (inflating fragment, YouTubePlayerView cant start without special Activity and so on).

What worked: I used SherlockFragmentActivity, FragmentManager (getSupportFragmentManager()) and YouTubePlayerSupportFragment. Instead of adding it to XML, I created everything from code.  My layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

and Java code:

```
package com.example.youtubetesting;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();

    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentz, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    fragment.initialize("Your API KEY HERE",
            new OnInitializedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0,
                        YouTubePlayer arg1, boolean arg2) {
                    if (!arg2) {
                        arg1.loadVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                }

            });
}

}
```

I dont know why Android was returning errors when I was inflating views in normal way, but this works perfectly.

Comment: Both this and juandg's answer appear to be correct.  This answer provides some concrete example so I flagged Damian's most complete.

Comment: Did you get fullscreen properly with this?

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** use both a `YouTubeBaseActivity` and a `SherlockActivity` at the same time, at least not in a practical way.

Instead it's a lot easier if you just use a `SherlockFragmentActivity` to host a [YouTubePlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment)

The `YouTubePlayerFragment` contains a `YouTubePlayerView` just like the `YouTubeBaseActivity` that would let you play YouTube videos.

If you need a tutorial about Fragments on Android you can start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: in fact, you will need to use a YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Just use the `Fragment` variant and save yourself all the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the source code of the class `com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity` and I put it in my project as `my.package.SherlockYoutubeActivity`, and I replaced "`extends Activity`" with "`extends YouTubeBaseActivity`."
in my activity then I inherited from this class like this:

```
public class MyVideoActivity extends SherlockYoutubeActivity implements OnInitializedListener
```

Comment: Is this bad practice? Going to use the top answer but why the downvote?

Comment: I have implemented this solution and it works perfectly.
Need to remember to update the class SherlockYoutubeActivity when you update the library Sherlock.

Comment: I have successfully as well, I don't think there's anything wrong with this