# Solving the Java Interface Diamond Issue

Tags: java, interface, diamond-problem

In the past (Java 7 and before), Java classes and interfaces served different roles: classes for abstracting method implementation; interfaces for abstracting object structure. However, since Java 8, interfaces can now define a method implementation using default methods. This leads to a problem known as the "diamond problem".

An interface `A` with a method `execute()` is extended by interfaces `B` and `C` containing default implementations of `execute()`. If a class then implements `B` and `C`, there is ambiguity to which default implementation of `execute()` should be run.

```
interface A {
    public void execute();
}

interface B extends A {
    default void execute() { System.out.println("B called"); }
}

interface C extends A {
    default void execute() { System.out.println("C called"); }
}

class D implements B, C {
}
```

Given the class definitions above, when `(new D()).execute()` is executed, what will be printed (if anything): "`B called`", or "`C called`"?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question. It's an attempt to document an already known and documented side-issue since Java 8.

Comment: Just edited to properly define the question: which `execute()` implementation from `B` or `C` is called when `(new D()).execute()` is run.

Comment: No need to ask this question, just try to compile it with your java compiler.

Comment: Ah, did not see that one.

Comment: Another related question: [Implementing two interfaces with two default methods of the same signature in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685930/implementing-two-interfaces-with-two-default-methods-of-the-same-signature-in-ja)

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two implementations for `execute()` in `D`, the compiler will have no idea which implementation to use. In other words, this program will not compile.

**The Resolution**

The solution is D needs to create a new implementation of `execute()`, such that when `(new D()).execute()` is called, the compiler directly calls `execute()` in `D` rather than trying (and failing) to figure out which implementation from `B` or `C` to run.

```
class D implements B, C { // D does not need to implement A, since B and C already do

    @Override
    public void execute() { // new implementation defined in A
        B.super.execute(); // calls execute() defined by B
        C.super.execute(); // calls execute() defined by C
    }

}
```

In this example, `(new D()).execute()` will print -

`B called`

`C called`

**Notes**

If `B` and `C` are both classes, `D` cannot exist as a child of `B` and `C` since Java doesn't allow multiple-inheritance. However, if `B` xor `C` are classes, `D` does not need to reimplement `execute()` since it is extensably defined in the parent class.

```
interface B extends A {
    default void execute() { System.out.println("B called"); }
}

class C implements A {
    public void execute() { System.out.println("C called"); }
}

class D extends C implements B { 
    // Will compile correctly since C provides the implementation for execute()

}
```

In this example, `(new D()).execute()` will print "`C called`".

`D` extends `C` so will use the method implementations of `C` if not overridden.

Comment: Your paragraph 'Answer' is not the answer, your first sentence is. 'Answer' should be something like 'Resolution'

Comment: You are correct there, just changed it.