# java how can I overcome multiple inheritance and diamond problam

Tags: java, interface, extends, implements, diamond-problem

I'm trying to understand how can I overcome the "diamond problem" in JAVA
let's say I have these 3 interfaces:

```
interface Alpha{
    public default int methodA() {
        int result=0;
        System.out.println("Print from Alpha methodA");
        return result+4;
    }
}

//**********************************

interface Betta extends Alpha {
    public default int methodA() {
        int result=0;
        System.out.println("Print from Betta methodA");
        return result+8;
    }
}
//*******************************

interface Gamma extends Alpha {
    public default int methodA() {
        int result=0;
        System.out.println("Print from Gamma methodA");
        return result+16;
    }
}
```

And that class:

```
public class Delta implements Betta,Gamma {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Delta cObj=new Delta();
    cObj.methodA();
}
```

how can I get class Delta  giving me the output of Alpha interface? 
Any other way than changing it to "Delta implements Alpha"?

Comment: You can't access a method which has been overridden. If you need access to it you need to add a method you can call which can class this method e.g. to Betta or Gamma.

Comment: If okay then you can define `static` method in Alpha interface and call it from Delta class.

Comment: Have you tried compiling this?

Comment: Thank you  Peter Lawrey I'll try it

Comment: SachinSarawgi but if I do it than there is no use for Betta and Gamma,am I right?

Comment: @Liana you are correct, I just tried to give a solution. In your case it may not be useful.

Comment: yes,I get that error "Duplicate default methods named methodA with the parameters () and () are inherited from the types Gamma and Betta"   @Klitos Kyriacou

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing Betta and Gamma in class Delta then you must be getting compilation error in Delta to override default method. Because if two interfaces have same default method then the class implementing both must define its own implementation.

You can do it like :

```
public class Delta implements Betta, Gamma {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Delta cObj = new Delta();
        cObj.methodA();
    }

    @Override
    public int methodA() {
        return Betta.super.callSuperMethodA();
    }
}

public interface Betta extends Alpha {

    public default int methodA() {
        int result = 0;
        System.out.println("Print from Betta methodA");
        return result + 8;
    }

    //Call this from Delta default method
    public default int callSuperMethodA() {
        return Alpha.super.methodA();
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought about it too but I get the ""Print from Betta methodA" and when I try to use Alpha.methodA(); inside the Betta interface I get both "Print from Betta methodA" and ""Print from Alpha methodA" @Rohit Gulati

Comment: sorry mybad, I misinterpreted your question, we cannot access it. Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24280376/5803493).
We will have to make it static or extend Alpha.

Comment: Alternative: You can add one more default method in Betta where you call Alpha Default method. Updated above post. @Liana

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I get it now

Answer (score 0):

You can either turn Alpha's method to static

```
public interface Alpha {
public static int methodA(){
    int result = 0;
    System.out.println("Print from Alpha methodA");
    return result+4;
}}
```

or you can create a method referring to Alpha's method in Betta or Gamma.

A third optional solution to this would be deleting both Gamma's and Betta's default implementations, meaning emptying both of them intirely.