# Interface semantic understanding

Tags: java

Found this question here at stack overflow:
[Can you call the parent interface's default method from an interface that subclasses that interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273694/can-you-call-the-parent-interfaces-default-method-from-an-interface-that-subcla)

```
new BFunctionalInterface(){
            @Override
            public void doWork() {
            }}.doSomeWork();
            System.out.println("WUK WUK");
```

I understand its an anonymous class.But what does calling doSomeWork with a 
"." inside doWork mean?Does it call the  implementation of A or B?

Comment: I didn't see any where `doSomeWork()` defined when you do anonymous implementation of  the interfac e`BFunctionalInterface`

Comment: Its been called inside the BImplementorClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's calling `doSomeWork` on the object created via `new BFunctionalInterface`.

This is clearer if you format it reasonably and remove the extra `}` from the excerpt (it seems to be the closing `}` on an enclosing block you haven't shown the start of) which is misleading:

```
new BFunctionalInterface() {
    @Override
    public void doWork() {
    }
}.doSomeWork();
System.out.println("WUK WUK");
```

Clearer still if you assign it to a local and then make the call:

```
BFunctionalInterface instance = new BFunctionalInterface() {
    @Override
    public void doWork() {
    }
};
instance.doSomeWork();
System.out.println("WUK WUK");
```

Other than the second creating a variable, those do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Okay so its just like creating an  object of class Foo and calling its method