# Can an interface have partially implemented methods?

Tags: java, interface

Can an interface have partially implemented methods? This is a question which asked from me in an exam. I don't have a clear idea on "**partially implemented**". Is it mean that methods of that interface has some operations? But normally we are having only the methods without body in the interfaces. So if anyone can answer me I would be more thankful.

Comment: java 8 added the feature called default methods https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way an `interface` can have "partially" implemented methods is through Java 8's `default` methods:

```
// will compile in Java 8 only
interface Foo {
    default void foo() {
        System.out.println("Default foo implementation");
    }
}
```

The standard way before Java 8 (and still valid conceptually depending on your scope) is to have a[n abstract] class providing a method with default behavior for its children.

Comment: Thank you very much Mena for your reply. It was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can interpret this question so as to have a "yes" answer is to implement the "partial" part of the method as a default method and then to [explicitly call the default method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976615) from the method which overrides it:

```
public interface Swallow {

    default double getMaxAirspeed() {
        // Partial implementation of the method to be called by its full implementation, which should override this default method 
        return 1.0;
    }

}

public class AfricanSwallow implements Swallow {

    public double getMaxAirspeed() {
        final double initialValue = Swallow.super.getMaxAirspeed();
        return initialValue * 2;
    }

}
```