# Invoke non-abstract method of super interface in concrete class

Tags: java, interface, java-8, super, default-method

The `Calculator` interface has `calculate` abstract method and `ramdom()` non-abstract method. I want to use **super** `ramdom()` and also **Override** `ramdom()` at concrete class `CalculatorImpl`. My question is why I have to call like that `Calculator.super.ramdom()` ? Why `super.ramdon()` don't work?

```
public interface Calculator {

    double calculate(int a);

    default double ramdom() {
        System.out.println("Calculator ramdom");
        return Math.random();
    }

}

class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {

    @Override
    public double calculate(int a) {
        // calling super.ramdom() will get [The method ramdom() is undefined for
        // the type Object error]
        return Calculator.super.ramdom() * a;
    }

    @Override
    public double ramdom() {
        System.out.println("CalculatorImpl ramdom");
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to spell random](http://www.spellweb.com/how-do-you-spell/random)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your exact question: when you use super inside a class ... you are "pointing" to the class it is extending; in this case Object.

But Object does not have a method random that you could be calling.

Therefore you have to make it explicit "where" random is actually coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the override of `ramdom` in `CalculatorImpl`. It will implicitly used the `default` implementation from `Calculator`.

```
class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {

@Override
public double calculate(int a) {
    // calling super.ramdom() will get [The method ramdom() is undefined for
    // the type Object error]
    return Calculator.super.ramdom() * a;
}
/* Remove the Override and the default implementation will be used
@Override
public double ramdom() {
    System.out.println("CalculatorImpl ramdom");
    return 0;
}
*/
}
```

Keyword `super` is used to call the **inherited class** and not the **implemented interface**. But here you have no inheritance except the implicit `Object` which does not have a `random` method

**Edit**: I might have missunderstood your question. If you want to override and call the default implementation, check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976487/explicitly-calling-a-default-method-in-java) provided by Sasha Salauyou

Comment: in fact, removing `@Override` will not affect anything. It is just an annotation telling compiler you're gonna override some method (so it could check the signature and tell if you're mistaken)

Comment: @Sasha Salauyou I am certainly not talking about the annotation but the whole method, as the code sample shows ;)

Comment: I see, but it also has no sense. OP says they need overriden method as well.

Comment: @Sasha Salauyou you're right. I will be editing this post

Comment: @SashaSalauyou my question is why I have to call explicitly ? I know how to call a default method explicitly

Comment: @ortis my question is why I have to call explicitly ? I know how to call a default method explicitly

Comment: @Alice the answer is: this is rule of the language