# How to get the interface name inside the constructor of implementing class?

Tags: java

How to get the Interface Name of a Class which is implementing that Interface from inside the Constructor of that implementing class in Java implementation?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean. Please can you show some example code.

Comment: Possibly via `getClass().getInterfaces()` (but you may also need to walk up the tree using `getClass().getSuperclass()` if the interface is specified in a superclass).

Comment: Are you trying to explicitely call the default methods from the interfaces like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19976615/3196458)?

Comment: Per @AndyTurner, here's a tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getinterfaces.htm