# Can I use default method in is override?

Tags: java

lets say we have interface

```
interface Interf {
      void a();
      default void saySomething(){
       print("123");
      }
}
```

and class

```
class Cls implements Interf {
     void a()
     {
         print();
     }
}
```

can we sommeehow use default method? like for super methods:

```
class Cls implements Interf {
....
     void saySomething()//prints "123456"
    {
      super.saySomething(); //something like this but for calling default implemntation
      print("456");
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this is a dupe i have to say it really looks weird to implement, or rather what has to be written.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976487/explicitly-calling-a-default-method-in-java

Comment: Really? I closed this one before your comment @BalajiKrishnan

Comment: did not flag it.. just added a comment so you could take a look.