# Java default method Multiple inheritance super keyword is confusing

Tags: java

```
public interface A{
  default void decorateWithPaints(){
    System.out.println("Decorate in A using paints");
  }
}

public interface B{
  default void decorateWithPaints(){
    System.out.println("Decorate in B using paints");
  }
}

public class C implements A,B{
  @Override
  public void decorateWithPaints() {
    A.super.decorateWithPaints();
  }
}
```

`A.super.decorateWithPaints()` what does this actually means???
   We know that we can access super class method using `super` keyword . But in this case we have to give interface name to access default interface method. It is really confusing me.

Comment: It means: invoke the default implementation of the method from `A`. Otherwise, it's ambiguous, because there are two super interfaces implementing the method.

Comment: Is it compiling ? Implementing two interfaces with a similar method with default. I though it was not permited

Comment: @AxelH see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19976615/3788176. Probably the case you're thinking of is where the method isn't overridden in the concrete class.

Comment: @AndyTurner right, thanks ! So indeed, this is obviously to precise witch implementation to use, this was not a problem in Java since multiple inheritance was not permitted, but now that interface have implementation too, this could be ambigous.

Comment: Actually i mean Interface with super keyword means what?