# what is classname.super.method means?

Tags: java, oop, super

I saw this in book:

```
class Student implements Person,Named
{
    public String getName(){return Person.super.getName();}
}
```

There is a same method in `Person` and `Named` called `getName()`.

I have never seen the grammar above before.

I know `super.getName()` means it called the parent's method, but why must it be called with `Person` there?

Comment: `Person` and `Named` can have conflicting implementations of the same method.

Comment: You implemented two interfaces. There may a `getName()` in those interfaces

Comment: Question is missing a [mcve] of the other two interfaces

Comment: @OneCricketeer This is the question itself.