# Why do we need super keyword to call default interface methods?

Tags: java, oop, interface, super

In the below code when I am having a class implementing two interfaces with same default method signature it ask me to override it. but in the overriden method why I have to use super keyWord to call the default method.

```
package practice;



interface interA{

public default void AImp(){
    System.out.println("Calling Aimp from interA");
}
}


interface interB{

public default void AImp(){
    System.out.println("Calling Aimp from interB");
}
}

public class Practice implements interA,interB {

public static void main(String[] args) {


Practice inter = new Practice();

    inter.AImp();

}

@Override
public void AImp() {

    interA.super.AImp();
}
}
```

I can do the same b using below code:

```
@Override
public void AImp() {
    interA inter = new Practice();
    inter.AImp();
}
```

Comment: [Java tutorial on `super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) explains why super is necessary. Your second approach will produce a neverending loop. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976487/explicitly-calling-a-default-method-in-java) might also be interesting for you.

Comment: Have you been teached, to use lowercase for methods? It helps faster orientation a lot.

Comment: @MalteHartwig that tutorial does not deal with diamond at all.

Comment: @Basilevs "but in the overriden method why I have to use super keyWord to call the default method." That sounds to me as if Op doesn't really understand what instance methods do in a class hierarchy. As far as I can see, his alternative code at the end shows that there are basic misunderstandings unrelated to multiple inheritance. Especially as that last snippet will most definitely **not** do "the same".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explicitly calling a default method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976487/explicitly-calling-a-default-method-in-java)

Comment: Actually, there is another page of that tutorial that has this exact case (multiple inheritance of a default method): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Based on comment from @MalteHartwig.</sub>

Direct quote from [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html):

> If two or more independently defined default methods conflict, or a
>   default method conflicts with an abstract method, then the Java
>   compiler produces a compiler error. You must explicitly override the
>   supertype methods.
>
> Consider the example about computer-controlled cars that can now fly.
>   You have two interfaces (OperateCar and FlyCar) that provide default
>   implementations for the same method, (startEngine):
>
> ```
> public interface OperateCar {
>     // ...
>     default public int startEngine(EncryptedKey key) {
>         // Implementation
>     }
> }
>
> public interface FlyCar {
>     // ...
>     default public int startEngine(EncryptedKey key) {
>         // Implementation
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> A class that implements both OperateCar and FlyCar must override the
>   method startEngine. You could invoke any of the of the default
>   implementations with the super keyword.
>
> ```
> public class FlyingCar implements OperateCar, FlyCar {
>     // ...
>     public int startEngine(EncryptedKey key) {
>         FlyCar.super.startEngine(key);
>         OperateCar.super.startEngine(key);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The name preceding super (in this example, FlyCar or OperateCar) must
>   refer to a direct superinterface that defines or inherits a default
>   for the invoked method. This form of method invocation is not
>   restricted to differentiating between multiple implemented interfaces
>   that contain default methods with the same signature. You can use the
>   super keyword to invoke a default method in both classes and
>   interfaces.

Comment: `package practice;



interface interA{
 
 public default void AImp(){
  System.out.println("Calling Aimp from interA");
 }
}


interface interB extends interA{
 
 public default void AImp(){
  System.out.println("Calling Aimp from interB");
 }
}

public class Practice implements interA,interB{

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  
Practice inter = new Practice();

  inter.AImp();

 }

 @Override
 public void AImp() {
  interB.super.AImp();
 }
 
 
}
`

Comment: The above code prints "Calling Aimp from interB" when interB.super.AImp() is invoked. But the super of interB is interA interface so it should print "Calling Aimp from interA".

Answer (score 0):

You didn't just override, you have implemented interfaces with same named methods. More exactly, you have implemented two interfaces and you have to resolve [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) no matter what code you want to run in AImpl. IDE required of you to override **because** of diamond hierarchy. Once you have provided code, **interA.super** is used as a way to navigate to desired code.

Answer (score 0):

Practice class implements 2 interfaces.
Namely InterA and InterB.
The idiom used specifies which one of the 2 default methods you wish to call.
This is because the 2 methods have the same signature.

However when you override the signature on the Practice class like that:

```
package practice;

interface InterA {

    public default void AImp() {
        System.out.println("Calling Aimp from interA");
    }
}

interface InterB {

    public default void AImp() {
        System.out.println("Calling Aimp from interB");
    }
}

public class Practice implements InterA, InterB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Practice inter = new Practice();

        inter.AImp();

    }

//    @Override
//    public void AImp() {
//
//        interA.super.AImp();
//    }
    @Override
    public void AImp() {
        InterA inter = new Practice();
        inter.AImp();
    }
}
```

You do not get the same result.
You get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at practice.Practice.AImp(Practice.java:35)
at practice.Practice.AImp(Practice.java:35)
at practice.Practice.AImp(Practice.java:35)
at practice.Practice.AImp(Practice.java:35)
at practice.Practice.AImp(Practice.java:35)
at practice.Practice.AImp(Practice.java:35)
at practice.Practice.AImp(Practice.java:35)
```

You reference an instance of Practice through the InterA interface, that forces the use of the implemented interface,which will instantiate again Practice and call AImp . This will recursively be repeated until a java.lang.StackOverflowError is thrown.

Comment: No this didn't happen I am successfully able to execute the code and get the same result. it did not throw any stackOverFlow error. The output is : Calling Aimp from interA

Comment: Running the code throws the StackOverflowError  as expected.  How did you verify?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the use of word super is confusing here. As pointed out by @Basilevs, whenever there is a conflict of default methods from two interfaces implemented by a class, it will result into a compilation error (Fair Enough). To remove this error, the class must provide its implementation of that method, so compiler is not confused any more about which method it will invoke.

The next thing after resolving the compilation error is how to call the default implementations of the interface by-passing the implementation provided by the class itself. To do that, the method will be called with the name of the direct implemented superinterface that has defined the method.

In the example above, posted by @Ashraf Mulla, the call interB.super.AImp(); prints "Calling AImp from B" because that is what it is supposed to do as per Java specifications. Interface B is the direct interface which has the implementation for AImp method, so that will be executed.

To test further, one can also try having third interface which extends both interface A and interface B , which will need to provide its over-ridden implementation of AImp method to overcome compilation error. If a class, implements all the three interfaces (interface A, interface B and interface C extending A and B), then calling interA.super.Aimp, interB.super.Aimp will result in compilation error with the exact description to call with interC.super, that being the direct super interface having the method definition.