# Explicitly calling a default method in java - when the implemented interface uses generics

Tags: generics, inheritance, interface, java-8, default-method

This questions is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976487/explicitly-calling-a-default-method-in-java) with a twist.

I have an interface such as :

```
@Repository
public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, String>{

  // some other methods here 

 default Invoice save(Invoice invoice) {

        //I do sth here

        return JpaRepository.super.save(invoice); // wonT work
    }

}
```

**How can i call the save method of the implemented JPA interface?**

---

Update: 
Indeed i noticed, save is not a default in the extended `JPARepository` interface

In this case, what would be the best way of achieving this ?

- override save method
- call the parent save method in the overridden method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default method you defined is helpless as Spring will implement out of the box a method with the same erasure (see `CrudRepository.save()`).

Here you don't invoke a `default` method of an interface :

```
JpaRepository.super.save(invoice);
```

you invoke the abstract `save()` method of `CrudRepository`.
But it cannot compile as it is `abstract`.
It could work as in the quoted question if  the `JpaRepository`super class defined a default `save()` method but that is not the case.

> In this case, what would be the best way of achieving this ?

You could create a `default` method with a distinct name and from it call  `save()` that at runtime will invoke the runtime `InvoiceRepository` instance :

```
default Invoice saveInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
    // I do sth here
    ...
    return save(invoice); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the method `save()` is not **`default`**. From the code, its defined as :

```
<S extends T> S save(S var1); // abstract, public
```

***Note*** - Worth mentioning, the code belongs to the artifact *`org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.0.9.RELEASE`*.

Or if I could say, your inference is incorrect, *"`default` is not implied by default."*

Comment: indeed i noticed, save is not a default in the JPARepository interface