# Explicitly calling a default method in Groovy

Tags: inheritance, groovy, java-8, interface, default-method

This question is very like the other one discussing [Explicitly calling a default method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976487/explicitly-calling-a-default-method-in-java), but in Groovy code(ver. 2.4.16)

```
public interface Interface { // a Java interface
    default void call() {}
}

public class Test implements Interface { // a Groovy class
    @Override
    public void call() {
        Interface.super.call() // compile error: Groovy:The usage of 'Class.this' and 'Class.super' is only allowed in nested/inner classes.
    }
}
```

On the other hand, default methods are very like Trait in Groovy, and the following code compiles OK

```
public trait Trait { // a Groovy trait
    void call() {}
}

public class Test implements Trait { // a Groovy class
    @Override
    public void call() {
        Trait.super.call() // compiles OK
    }
}
```

So, how to explicitly call a default method in a Groovy subclass?

Comment: In Groovy 2.4 you can't specify default methods on interfaces. However if you have a Java interface implemented by a Groovy class and its override method wishes to invoke the default method, would it be "super.whatever()"

Comment: If the super method comes from a trait, you can use the Type.super.whatever() syntax.

Comment: @emilles In Groovy 2.5 it seems that neither `Interface.super.whatever()` nor `super.whatever()` works... It searches for the super implementation in the parent class, but not in the implemented interface. Any suggestion?

Comment: Seems to be fixed only in Groovy 4.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9909