# In java 8, implementing two interfaces with same name method, first method dont have body, second does

Tags: java, java-8

In java 8, got two interfaces with same name method.

First method don't have body

```
interface Interface01 {
    void method();
}
```

and other have default body

```
interface Interface02 {
    default void method() { 
        System.out.println("This is from: Interface02 - method()");
    }
}
```

How to call second method() in first @overriden method(). Is it possible?

```
class ChildClass implements Interface01, Interface02 {
    
    public void method() { //override method from Interface01
        
        method();          // calling method from Interface02
    }
}
```

Is this possible, reference to interface02.method()?

Comment: Have you tried actually creating `Interface02` and seeing if it compiles?

Comment: `Interface02.super.method();` (now where is that duplicate.. found it [Explicitly calling a default method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19976487))

Comment: @Pshemo not working by the way..

Comment: regarding @JacobG. comment, you may find your IDE gives you another hint with respect to Interface02.method(). Mine did. Haven't followed java for the last few years so it's cool to see this feature.

Comment: @acakojic Are you sure? Works fine for me: https://ideone.com/wviocU

Comment: acakojic, you forgot the `default` keyword on Interface02.method() which may account for why it's not working for you. Like @Pshemo it works fine for me.

Comment: @Pshemo Yup this is working my bad. Need to change public to default method(){}.

Comment: @MichaelWelch I'm learning java-8 right now. Was writting java-7.. I'm too old for this.. My brain got open two many tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird syntax, but it is available:

```
class ChildClass implements Interface01, Interface02 {
    
    public void method() { //override method from Interface01
        
        Interface02.super.method();          // calling method from Interface02
    }
}
```

You can use this here. You can also use it if both I1 and I2 have a default method - then your `ChildClass` wouldn't compile either (javac forces you to explicitly pick which of the two impls you want, or if you want to write an entirely new one - that's because java, by the design, does not want the order in which you listed your interfaces to change what your code means).

Answer (score 1):

```
class ChildClass implements Interface01, Interface02 {
    
    public void method() { //override method from Interface01
        
        Interface02.super.method();          // calling method from Interface02
    }
}
```