# How to call a method of super class from parent class. How to call the same method from interface?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am learning java and I am trying to recreate a scenario where A class is extending an abstract class and also implementing an interface. Each abstract class and interface have a same method defined in them. Now from the class which is extending and implementing, I want to call the implementations of both the parents. I tried to recreate this scenario as below but it gave me the error: not an enclosing class: A

```
interface C {
  default void m1(){
      System.out.println("C");
  }
}

abstract class A{
  abstract void display();
  void m1(){
      System.out.println("A");
  }
}

class B extends A implements C{
    public void m1(){
    }
    void display() {
        C.super.m1();
        A.super.m1(); // error: not an enclosing class: A
    }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A obj = new B();
    obj.display();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly name a superclass to invoke its methods, because a Java class can only extend one superclass, so `MyClass.super.method()` is unambiguous. In fact, you needn't even name the child class at all: `super.method()` is also unambiguous due to Java's single inheritance model.

You do need to explicitly name a super-interface to invoke its methods, because a Java class can implement multiple interfaces, so `MyInterface.super.method()` is necessary to identify which interface is being invoked.

```
interface MyInterface {
    default void m1(){
        System.out.println("MyInterface");
    }
}

abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    public void m1(){
        System.out.println("MyAbstractClass");
    }
}

public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void m1() {
        super.m1();             // MyAbstractClass
        MyClass.super.m1();     // MyAbstractClass
        MyInterface.super.m1(); // MyInterface
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new MyClass().m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know explicitly naming interfaces like this was part of the language.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, [it’s a brand new feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19976487/2711488)…