# How do I extend two classes

Tags: android, extends

I have this android application and I am trying to extend two classes at the same time. I have this code:

```
public class TimelineFragment extends Fragment {
    public class TimelineFragment extends Activity {
        //all codes here
    }
}
```

On my second `TimelineFragment`, it has an error that says: The nested type TimelineFragment cannot hide an enclosing type

Comment: thats something you dont see everyday.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending from two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836662/extending-from-two-classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have this android application and I am trying to extend two classes at the same time

That is not possible. Java does not support multiple inheritance.

> I have this code

Given your class name is `TimelineFragment`, one presumes that it should extend `Fragment`. Whatever problem you are trying to solve via multiple inheritance will need to be solved in some other way. For example, if you are trying to perform operations on the activity that hosts your fragment, you can call `getActivity()` from the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inharitance is not possible in Java, and therefore in Android.

Answer (score 0):

multiple inheritance is not possible in java so therefore u cant't use it in android as well.
Well one thing you can do is to create interfaces instead of class and implement any no. of interfaces you want and their methods.