# android extended class unable to resolve

Tags: android

**Error Cannot resolve symbol "pdf.viewer.activity"**
[code and error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2pe0.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity ,net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */

Context context;
/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
PDFView pdfView;

String[] abc={"kotlin.pdf","book1.pdf","book2.pdf"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 pdfView= (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
   pdfView.fromAsset(abc[1]).load();




}
}
```

Comment: you can only extend one class so remove appcompat

Comment: You can only Extend a single class. And implement Interfaces from many sources. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5836735/3168859)

Comment: Sir, Thank you! for your answer!

Sir, I found this error after removing the AppCompatActivity! Error:(22, 37) error: package com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Theres no multiple inheritance in Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity ,net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity {
```

Should be only one class, probably PdfViewerActivity in your case:

```
public class MainActivity extends net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity {
```

Comment: Respected Sir, Thanks for your prompt reply!

Comment: i removed the AppCompatActivity ,

Comment: Sir, I found this error after removing the AppCompatActivity!
Error:(22, 37) error: package com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer does not exist