# To extend a class which is already extends by ebean model class

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I am developing a java playframework project.I am using Book class which is a sub class.It is extended from Item abstract class.I want to use com.avaje.ebean library and extend the Book class to add data to the database.So it means I have to extend two classes.
Is there alternative way of doing this?
Can you give me any solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending from two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836662/extending-from-two-classes)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Multi-level inheritance:
`class a {}
class b extends a{}
class c extends b{}`

or else you have to go for interface concept, there you can implement n no. of classes

Comment: So if I extend my abstract class using ebean model class. will I be able to add sub class data to the database.