# How to extend two classes in an Activity?

Tags: java, android

This is the activity so I want to extend the JavaFX Activity class here since we can't extend two classes in java how do I extend the class next to AppCompatActivity.

```
public class BarchartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barchart);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is single Inheritance, you can only implement Multiple interfaces

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836662/extending-from-two-classes look here for answer.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: You have told us how you want to do something. but not what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Java can only extends from one class, but many interfaces can be implemented